# How to get pending balance using bitcoin client/ bitcoin-cli?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind

I want to get the pending balance for my bitcoin client but I don't see any RPC call for it.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for answering my own question, but I just found the answer.

The RPC command to get pending/unconfirmed balance is `getunconfirmedbalance`